# How to inject a list of properties with name pattern or regular expression in Google Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, binding, guice

Using Google Guice, we can inject from property files like this:

```
@Inject(optional = true)
@Named("api.server.ip")
private final String ip = "localhost";
```

So what if I have a property file like this:

```
api.server.ip.1=10.11.12.13
api.server.port.1=3000
api.server.path.1=/maps
api.server.ip.2=10.11.12.14
api.server.port.2=3001
api.server.path.2=/phones
```

The mission is the application needs to access to multiple servers to call requests, so is there any way to inject properties using pattern in Google Guice, or any recommendation to solve this issue? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution coming from Google Guice but you can do something with [TypeListener](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) api.

Here is a piece of code which will inject fields annotated by my custom `Property` annotation -

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.MembersInjector;
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;
import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers;
import com.google.inject.spi.TypeEncounter;
import com.google.inject.spi.TypeListener;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PropertiesInjection {

    static class PropertiesModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindListener(Matchers.any(), new PropertiesTypeListener());
        }
    }

    static class PropertiesTypeListener implements TypeListener {

        public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
            Class<?> clazz = typeLiteral.getRawType();
            while (clazz != null) {
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.getType() == String.class && field.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
                        Property annotation = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                        typeEncounter.register(new PropertyInjector<T>(field, annotation.value()));
                    }
                }
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @interface Property {
        String value();
    }

    static class PropertyInjector<T> implements MembersInjector<T> {

        private final Field field;
        private final String key;

        PropertyInjector(Field field, String key) {
            this.field = field;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void injectMembers(T instance) {
            try {
                field.set(instance, PropertiesFileDataProvider.getValue(key));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    static class PropertiesFileDataProvider {

        private static final Map<String, String> PROPERTIES = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            PROPERTIES.put("api.server.ip", "localhost"); //load it from properties file. I am putting dummy values just for an example.
        }

        static String getValue(String key) {
            return PROPERTIES.getOrDefault(key, key);
        }
    }

    static class TestData {
        @Property("api.server.ip")
        private String property;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new PropertiesModule());
        TestData instance = injector.getInstance(TestData.class);

        System.out.println(instance.property); //prints localhost
    }
}
```